# How to thicken the size of the point and the thickness of the outline for the outward vector point？

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is the picture I made. I want to draw an outward arrow point at the origin of the coordinate axis to represent the x-axis, but the outward arrow point in this picture is too thin. I want to thicken the size of the point and the thickness of the circle. what should I do?
[image: f5]

where $x$ is very far from the origin of the coordinates, I want to make it below and left of the origin, what should I do, this is my code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(10cm,0)},y={(0,1cm)}]
    \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (0,1.5cm) node [left]  {$y$};
    \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (1.5cm,0) node [below]  {$z$};
    \node (123) at (0,0) {$\odot$};\node [ below left=of 123] {$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the size of the point put a filled circle at the origin and use `minimum size` to set its size. Analogously with  a circle (now `draw` instead of `fill`) and use e.g `thick` to have a thicker line.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(10cm,0)},y={(0,1cm)}]
        \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (0,1.5cm) node [left]  {$y$};
        \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (1.5cm,0) node [below]  {$z$};
        \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (-1.0cm,-1.0cm) node [right]  {$x$};
        \node[circle,draw, thick, inner sep=0pt,minimum size= 10pt]  at (0,0){};
        \node[circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size= 4pt] at (0,0) {};      
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Since the nodes will be empty, a similar result can be obtained using a shape:

```
    \draw[line width=0.8pt, inner sep=0pt] (0,0) circle [radius=5pt];           
    \draw[fill,inner sep=0pt] (0,0) circle [radius=1.5pt];
```

**UPDATE** after follow-up question:  the text $x$ just below the left of the origin.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x={(10cm,0)},y={(0,1cm)}]
        \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (0,1.5cm) node [left]  {$y$};
        \draw [-stealth](0,0) --++ (1.5cm,0) node [below]  {$z$};
        
        \node(cir)[circle,draw, line width=0.5pt, inner sep=0pt,minimum size= 8pt]  at (0,0){};
        \node [circle, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum size= 3pt] at (0,0) {}; 
        \node[below left=0pt and 0pt of cir, anchor= north east] at (0,0) {$x$};            
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I meant to add the text $x$ just below the left of the arrow point, without that extra horizontal line on the x-axis. How should this be done?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I meant to add the text $x$ just below the left of the $\odot$, without that extra horizontal line on the x-axis. How should this be done?(my english is poor sorry)